# Action pop-up for Photo in QGIS 3.22.5 not working with Windows 11?

Tags: qgis, qfield, photos, actions

I am attempting to use the action feature for photos described in Using QGIS and QField for Field Data Collection - https://www.line-45.com/post/using-qgis-and-qfield-field-data-collection.

This process has worked for me in the past but is no longer working since I upgraded to Windows 11.

Has anyone had similar issues or found a way to make Photo Action work with Windows 11?